# Ship files into ProgramFiles folder instead ProgramFiles(x86) folder using Wix

Tags: windows, installation, wix, windows-installer

I want to ship the files into **C:\Program Files** Folder instead of **C:\Program Files(x86)** folder even if it is 64 bit machine. I have tried variables '**ProgramFilesFolder**' and '**ProgramFiles64Folder**', but it is trying to ship the files to this **C:\Program Files(x86)** folder only. Also i have given the shipping path directly in wix project, but still it is shipping the files into wrong location.

Comment: The *Program Files* folder in a 64-bit OS is for 64-bit binaries. Are you authoring a 64-bit installer? Or are you just working around a bug in your application, that uses a hard-coded `C:\Program Files` folder? If this is the case, you need to fix the application.

Comment: Yes. I am working 64 bit installer only

Answer (score 0):

You say you are authoring a 64bit installer  but then you also say  "even if it is a 64bit machine".   A 64bit installer can ONLY be installed on a 64bit machine.  This would suggest to me you are authoring a 32bit installer.   A 32bit installer cannot install components to 64bit locations.

Assuming you are in fact authoring a 64bit installer, ProgramFiles64Folder should do the trick.  You haven't posted any source or any installer logs so it's impossible to say what you are doing wrong.  I would make sure your package is marked 64bit and that all of your components are marked 64bit.